# Laravel Resource Not Updating Table

Tags: php, laravel, crud, edit

I have a blade project for CRUD with resource type controller in Laravel. it did using update method, but not updating anything to table, but it sending a value in dd. how do i fix it ?

here the code

**1. Blade**

```
@foreach ($produk as $product)
    <div class="modal fade" id="editModal{{ $product->ID_produk }}" tabindex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="/admin/data-produk/{{ $product->ID_produk }}" method="POST" class="d-inline">
                    @method('PUT')
                    @csrf
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="eeditModalLabel">Edit data produk</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="ID_produk" class="col-form-label">ID: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ID_produk" id="ID_produk"
                                value="{{ $product->ID_produk }}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="nama_produk" class="col-form-label">Nama: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_produk" id="nama_produk"
                                value="{{ $product->nama_produk }}">
                        </div>
                        {{-- <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="gambar_produk" class="col-form-label">Gambar: </label>
                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="gambar_produk" id="gambar_produk">
                    </div> --}}
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="deskripsi_produk" class="col-form-label">Deskripsi:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="deskripsi_produk" id="deskripsi_produk" rows="10">
                                {{ $product->deskripsi_produk }}</textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="harga_produk" class="col-form-label">Harga: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="harga_produk" id="harga_produk"
                                value="{{ $product->harga_produk }}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="slug" class="col-form-label">Slug: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="slug" id="slug"
                                value="{{ $product->slug }}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="stock" class="col-form-label">Stock: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="stock" id="stock"
                                value="{{ $product->stock }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**2. Route**

```
Route::resource('/admin/data-produk', AdminProdukController::class)->middleware('auth');
```

**3. Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, Produk $product)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'nama_produk' => ['required'],
            'deskripsi_produk' => ['required'],
            'harga_produk' => ['required'],
            'slug' => ['required'],
            'stock' => ['required']
        ]);
        Produk::where('ID_produk', $product->ID_produk)
                ->update($validatedData);   
                
        return back()->with('berhasilEdit', 'Data produk berhasil diedit!');
    }
```

**4. Model**

```
class Produk extends Model{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $table = 'tabel_produk';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID_produk';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['nama_produk',
    'deskripsi_produk',
    'harga_produk',
    'slug',
    'stock'
    ];
}
```

**VALUE**
I do dd($validatedData); in controller after editing the value, and it shown here:
[image]

Comment: Whats the value of dd($product->ID_produk); ?

Comment: mind to see my edited model, and i did dd($product->ID_produk);. it appeared null :(

Comment: I'm seeing that there's `method="POST"` and also `@method('PUT')` at the form_action line. Maybe correct the POST to PUT to see whether that helps?

Comment: Still not posted what i asked for, what is the result of dd($product)?

Comment: somone solved it for me, and you asked about my dd($product). it show me the product id. not sure how it only show that, because im still waiting for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller do this

```
    public function update(Request $request,$productID)
        {
            $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'nama_produk' => ['required'],
                'deskripsi_produk' => ['required'],
                'harga_produk' => ['required'],
                'slug' => ['required'],
                'stock' => ['required']
            ]);
        $product=Produk::find($productID);
        $product=$product->update($validateData);
        return back()->with('berhasilEdit', 'Data produk berhasil diedit!');
        }
```

after that if you do `dd($product)` you will get updated product Value

Comment: ayoo it worked!.do you mind to explain to me what you edit and why?
Thanks